# store a result of a command into a variable using csh

Tags: unix, csh

I'm trying to store a result of a command into a variable so I can display it nicely along with some text in one long not have it display the output and then newline then my text, in my csh script.

```
#! /bin/csh -f


if ("$1" == "-f" && $#argv == 1 ) then
    grep 'su root' /var/adm/messages.[0-9] | cut -c 21-250
    grep 'su root' /var/adm/messages
else if( $#argv >  0 ) then
    echo "Usage : [-f]"
else
  grep 'su root' /var/adm/messages.[0-9] /var/adm/messages | wc -l
  printf "failed su attempts between Nov 02 and Oct 28\n"
endif
```

this command in the script

```
  grep 'su root' /var/adm/messages.[0-9] /var/adm/messages | wc -l
```

gives me 21 when i run it, and i want 21 to be stored in a variable.

so i can just display the output of

```
21 failed su attempts between Nov 02 and Oct 28
```

and not

```
21
failed su attempts between Nov 02 and Oct 28
```

or if theres an easier way that doesn't involve variables open to that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `set` and backticks (``). Something like

```
set count=`grep 'su root' /var/adm/messages.[0-9] /var/adm/messages | wc -l`
printf "$count failed su attempts between Nov 02 and Oct 28\n"
```

**or**

```
printf "%s failed su attempts between Nov 02 and Oct 28\n" "$count"
```

**or** without a variable, like

```
printf "%s failed su attempts between Nov 02 and Oct 28\n" \
    `grep 'su root' /var/adm/messages.[0-9] /var/adm/messages | wc -l`
```